# Converting raw text to key value pair

Tags: json, rest, post

I have a raw text which I have tested with postman and works just fine:

```
{
    "messages": [{
        "type": "text",
            "data": "&es[Tenemos la respuesta a su consulta. ¿Nos podría atender ahora?](xxxxxxxx, resolucion_consulta)"
        }],
    "from": "xxxxxx",
    "recipients": [
        {"whatsapp_id": "xxxxxxxx"}
    ]
}
```

However in the application where I'm really willing to use it I can only use Parameters and body as key-values.

How can I translate the json into key value pairs for the app I'm using?

Comment: it's not clear what the expected result is... how do you want your arrays returned as by definition they usually contain several values for the same "key". Any way you'll need some code to "flatten" the data.

Comment: You have to decode json. For example if you use PHP, then `$key_value_array = json_decode($your_json_string);`

Comment: the application where I need to put the information only allows key and value. For the from field it is clear that there is only one value, however for the recipient you can have multiple whatsappid and therefore I'm not clear if I can send whatever is included in the curly brackets. For the message I have type and text and I'm clear if again this can be set in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally learned that the application did not support other means. This has now been correct and the application now accepts raw data therefore my problem is now gone.